# Is there a way for function to stop execution until the setTimeout() time is over

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have a simple code like in below snippet to have alert whenever a button is clicked and alert is shown, that runs alright but with certain drawbacks (know that this is how `setTimeout` works).
Here when you click button 2,3,4 times , than alert is shown that many times only. But I want alert only 1 time which is called from 1st click and ignore further clicks until 3 second are complete for 1st click.

```js
function alertBtn() {
  setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("Alert is clicked so remain alerted");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alertBtn()">Alert me</button>
```

Is it possible with pure JavaScript way? It's may be similar to method that **SO** uses like we can't comment again within 5s(or something), the button is kinda disabled for that time interval. Kind of barrier for 5sec

Comment: how about using a helper to bind the click handler, like lodash's [`before()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#before)?

Comment: You'd likely have to finish any remaining javascript in the setTimeout() callback.

Comment: @EliranMalka can it be possible with pure JavaScript to stop invoking the function until 1st click time is completed.

Comment: @user1599011 don't get your point. Can you elaborate a little more

Comment: Can you disable your buttons until the timeout is finished?

Comment: Yes, surely that can be the solution too. @user1599011

Comment: @Rana, yes - `clearTimeout`. see Ran Turner's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `clearTimeout()` for that which cancels a timeout previously established by calling `setTimeout()`

```js
let time;
let clicked = false;
function alertBtn() {
  if (!clicked){
    clicked = true;
    clearTimeout(time);
    time = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
  }
} 

function alertFunc() {
  alert("Alert is clicked so remain alerted");
  clicked = false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alertBtn()">Alert me</button>
```

`clearTimeout` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout

[Debouncing and throttling in JavaScript](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/debouncing-and-throttling-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Ran for nice simple solution.Thought of this but it has some different functionalities like `alert ` will not happen until 3second of last click but I wanted to happen when 3second passed from 1st click

Comment: I modified the answer, hope this is what you're looking for (:

Comment: @RanTurner nope. Still doesn't show alert when hammering the button.

Comment: Try again. i checked it many times

Comment: ok now it works :D

Comment: Is it what you needed?

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, I will mark it as accepted in a short time and upvote too ; ) .

Comment: Glad I could help (:

Comment: @RanTurner can you tell about, how to make this function reusable like if there are other buttons too. So do I have to write again and again or it can be reusable

Comment: @Rana - please read this article. it will help you in managing you application code and i hope it will make some sense of how to treat debouncing and throttling in JavaScript 
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/debouncing-and-throttling-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```js
let clickedOnce = false;

function alertBtn() {
  if (!clickedOnce) {
    clickedOnce = true;
    setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
  }
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("Alert is clicked so remain alerted");
  clickedOnce = false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alertBtn()">Alert me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is still executing the function for each click

Comment: @Rana Re-try now :)

Comment: Well it is working now, but it is similar to other answer(completely). Do you have any other method to solve this problem but +1 for the response, thanks for that.

Comment: @Rana Yup, both of us came up with this solution at the same time approximately. My version just does, what you asked for and is therefor more lean :). Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking to do something called *throttling*. Here's an example of how to implement it:

```
const throttle = function (fn, delay) {
    let timeout;
    return function (...args) {
        if (!timeout) {
            const returnVal = fn.apply(this, args);

            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                timeout = undefined;
            }, delay);
            
            return returnVal;
        }
    };
};
```

That `throttle` function allows you to transform a normal function into a *throttled* function, which will only be executed the first time it is called in a given `delay` time (specified in milliseconds to match the behaviour of `setTimeout`).

It works by creating a new function that sets a timeout the first time it is called, and calls the initial function. Then, if the throttled function is called again before the timeout is finished, it won't call the initial function again.

If you want to throttle your function by 3 seconds, then you should pass the value `3000` as the `delay` argument so the timeout created lasts for 3 seconds. You can crete only a throttled function by passing an anonymous function to `throttle`, like this:

```js
const throttle = function (fn, delay) {
    let timeout;
    return function (...args) {
        if (!timeout) {
            const returnVal = fn.apply(this, args);

            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                timeout = undefined;
            }, delay);
            
            return returnVal;
        }
    };
};

const alertBtn = throttle(function () {
  alert("Alert is clicked so remain alerted");
}, 3000);
```

```html
<button onclick="alertBtn()">Alert me</button>
```

Comment: Well thanks for such a nice answer, I got this same answer from JavaScript room but thought there must be some easy or other way round as it is bit complicated to me. But here in you snippet on the 1st click `alert` is instant.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstood your question then. I thought you wanted the first click to work, but then there would be a "cooldown" period of 3 seconds before it works again? Sorry if I misunderstood you. If you're looking for the function not to fire until after a cooldown period has passed since the last time you tried to call the function, that's called *debouncing* and can be done in a similar way. Let me know if that's the case and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Can you provide link to it if any. And you have given a nice solution by the way.

Comment: I have a [debounce library on GitHub](https://github.com/cipscis/debounce) if you'd like to see some code, but it's written in TypeScript and a more complex solution than you need in this case since I use `Promise` to try to conserve the value returned by the debounced function. Here is an article explaining the concept of debouncing, in a JavaScript context: [JavaScript debounce function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach was to simply control the buttons `disabled` state via `setTimeout`. A handler does take care of exeuting the `alertFunc` and of disabling the button on click and initiate the time shifted active state of the latter ...

```js
function alertFunc() {
  alert("Alert is clicked so remain alerted");
}

function controlButtonAbility(btn) {
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => btn.disabled = false, 5000);
}

function handleButtonClick(evt) {
  const btn = evt.currentTarget;

  controlButtonAbility(btn);

  alertFunc();
}
document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
```

```html
<button>Alert me</button>
```

***Edit***

> *"Nice solution, thanks for response(+1). But can the alert too be executed after 3s time"*

sure ...

```js
function alertFunc() {
  alert("Alert is clicked so remain alerted");
}

function controlButtonAbility(btn) {
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => btn.disabled = false, 5000);
}

function handleButtonClick(evt) {
  const btn = evt.currentTarget;

  controlButtonAbility(btn);

  // alertFunc();
  setTimeout(alertFunc, 2000);
}
document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
```

```html
<button>Alert me</button>
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks for response(+1). But can the alert too be executed after 3s time